# Improving performance of Union All query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a pretty extended Union All query with `Union All` used 34 times as follows:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2  
(RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage) 
SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',
       PercentMatch,fw1.FunctionWeight,
       PercentMatch * fw1.FunctionWeight
FROM   
       dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname, @checkbool) mfn

       CROSS JOIN

       dbo.FunctionWeights fw1
WHERE
     @firstname is not null and fw1.FunctionId = 1 

UNION ALL
SELECT RowNumber, @MiddleName,'Middlename',
       PercentMatch, fw2.FunctionWeight,
       PercentMatch * fw2.FunctionWeight 
FROM   
       dbo.MatchMiddleName(@MiddleName, @checkbool) mmn
       CROSS JOIN
       dbo.FunctionWeights fw2

WHERE
@MiddleName IS NOT NULL AND
     fw2.FunctionId = 2 

UNION ALL
SELECT RowNumber, @LastName,'Lastname',
       PercentMatch, fw3.FunctionWeight,
       PercentMatch * fw3.FunctionWeight 
FROM   
       dbo.MatchLastName(@LastName, @checkbool) mln 
       CROSS JOIN
       dbo.FunctionWeights fw3
WHERE
@LastName IS NOT NULL AND
     fw3.FunctionId = 3 

UNION ALL...........
and so on.
```

`dbo.MatchFirstName` is an inline TVF which looks like this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION MatchFirstName (@FirstNameFromUser nvarchar(20) , @checkbool int)
    RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
    select RowId As RowNumber, PercentMatch from dbo.MATCH(@FirstNameFromUser, 'firstname' , @checkbool ) 

GO
```

It is calling a `dbo.Match` function which is a multiline UDF and has some logic contained in it for calculating the percentage match based on field names passed as parameters to it.
34 Union All's means collaboration of results from 35 `Inline TVF's` using select query based on 35 different columns individually in them.All these belong to one table.
Now since I can not afford to have 35 indexes but yet I want to avoid table scans as this query is taking pretty long.

Is there a work around to improve performance here ?

Comment: may be try creating a table variable and start inserting each query block into it rather than union all , see if it better.

Comment: Without even looking at this my first question (and concern) is the contents of the MatchLastName table function. What does that function look like? Is it an inline function or a multi statement function? if it is the latter that is going to be the biggest performance bottleneck.

Comment: @SeanLange: Fortunately, it is an inline TVF . Updated the question with its structure.

Comment: @Prashant: That was the approach I used first but sequential approach is not the solution to this. I need to have a set based approach or parallel processing for faster computation.

Comment: Are the parameters to the function always the variables? Is the cross join causing extra calls to the function vs. just calling it once and storing the parameters and joining that with the table?

Comment: Also, look at plan cache for CPU and I/O usage, it should tell you where the issues are.

Comment: @JamesZ: Yes, The parameters to the functions are always variables. cross join is calling inline TVF which in turn calls a multiline TVF that takes those variables and makes some calculations and returns a table.

Comment: But your table function calls another function. This has a very bad code smell to it. You have literally killed yourself here. Your Match function is a multi line table valued function which is about the worst possible thing you can do from a performance perspective in sql server. It is generally slower than cursors, while loops and scalar functions. Your performance problem lies in the fact that you are using a mTVF and then calling it 35 times.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But what could I replace it with ? Since it is being called from an inline TVF, I can not make it a procedure either. what option do I have besides it ?